# String Dataframe R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, duplicates

i am having some problems with my data frame
i have a string dataframe
and i want to remove duplicate of a certain word in each row
this is my data frame

[image]

and i want to remove duplicates of the word "boy" to get a new data frame look like this:
[image]

Any suggestions will be helpfull, thanks in advance

Comment: please if any one noe a similar question, give me the link i searched so long and did not get any results, may be i did not write the right phrase

Comment: Do you know which word is duplicated in advance or not?

Comment: yes i know it is the word boy, so basically i want the code to only affect the word boy, other words even if repeated the code should not affect them.